# Model IndexError after checking count()

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here's my code:

```
    qs = MyModel.objects.filter(blah = blah)
    if qs.count() > 0:
        a = qs[0].value

File "/home/libs/django/db/models/query.py", line 189, in __getitem__
   return list(qs)[0]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Is there any possibilty to cause this error, other than the record being deleted from the database by a concurrent process ?

Comment: I think your your model objects has no records. Thats may be another possibility

Comment: If it has no records how queryset count can be >0 ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not considering the possibility that no records are returned by the filter. Even though you use the `qs.count()` conditional, your return value assumes objects were returned.  Perhaps you might consider a function:

```
def myquery():
    qs = MyModel.objects.filter(blah = blah)
    try:
        return qs[0].value
    except IndexError:
        return None  # or raise an exception
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. But I'm not returning anything. The exception is raised from django libs. I just assign the value.